# Keeping track of users and photos they've viewed

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, user-tracking, nosql

I have a very high traffic site with lots of photos on it and am trying to track which photo each user has viewed.

My first instinct would be a SQL table with two columns:  user_id & photo_id.    But,  that wouldn't scale to my traffic level,  and the table would get unmanageable very quickly.
Any recommendations for anoher solution, either SQL or NoSQL (mongodb,couch,redis,...)

My code is mostly PHP if that matters.

Thanks!

*Edit* There are 10s of millions of views day.

*Edit* I don't need to know the total times a user viewed a particular photo,  just whether its been viewed at all by that user

Comment: You can add the photo IDs to the session and update the DB in bulk, so instead of updating every single photo they see you can update WHERE id IN (5, 10, 15, whatever ids). The negative side of doing this is that if the user browses to n-1 images and then logs out never to return you've lost the logging of n-1 images.

Comment: Thanks Jim -- are you saying do a bulk insert?    (not exactly an update?).    That would help a lot,  but the table would still get enormous quickly.   In a week or so it would be unmanageable.

Comment: Ah, I guess I logged on SO a little too early today. You will have to do multiple insert queries, but if you're using prepared statements you will benefit from queries 2-15 (or whichever number you decide) are prepared when you execute them.

How large do you expect the table to get? SQL can handle millions of rows. Also you could look into splitting up the table / sharding.

Comment: It would be tens of millions per day most likely

Comment: Typed in the answer field by mistake. You could reduce the amount of records by adding a third column like views. So you would have like: 102 120 5, 130 89 3, 342 430 21 etc. This ideally is grouping the photo_id to the user. But you would still have a lot of records from the same user_id due to viewing other photos.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a collection with { _id:Generated automagically, pictureID, viewerID }

with find( pictureID, viewerID ).limit(1) and an index on pictureID **AND** viewerID will make checking super ultra fast level 99. very important to set the index. I use find().limit(1) because its faster than findOne, at least from the current benchmarks.

why not have one entry per user with an array of viewed images? because searching through the array is slower than searching for a whole document in a collection. 10 million images? no problem. this is where mongodb shines. its designed to scale for big-ass databases like yours. As long as your documents are less than 16 mb, and with 3 properties, it is :) you have little to worry about.

When you delete an image, just db.viewed.remove( { pictureID : pictureID } ) and it will remove all relating the image.

db.viewed.remove( { viewerID : viewerID } ) for when you remove a user! Don't do this when the user deletes the image or the account. Do this at maintenance time or say, once an hour. Create a collection with pendingRemovingImages and pendingRemovingUsers where you store the things you want removed. check **$in** to perform bulk removal by images and/or by users.

I find your question to be most exciting and I feel strongly that you should go in my direction.

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob Accept the question if it satisfies, please.

Comment: Discipol,  this might work,  I am still a little wary of the size though.   I am looking at 10s of millions per day (lots of users AND lots of photos).  Would this be able to hold up to 1,000 days * 10M views per day?

Comment: In theory, yes. You might see the hdd space going into hundreds of gigs. Is your website google or something? :P

Answer (score 1):

You can give Redis a try. Redis supports PHP very well, with Redis, you can store the viewing history of a particular photo in a hashmap.

```
$map = 'views|' . $photo_id;
// this line is called whenever a user view a photo
$redis->hset($map, $uid, time());
// this line is called to test whether a user viewed a photo
$redis->hget($map, $uid);
```

Redis is fast enough. But one thing you should know about Redis is that it stores all data in memory, so if the data eventually exceed the physical memory, you have to shard the data by your own.

Also you can try SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), which has similar APIs to Redis, also supports PHP well(http://www.ideawu.com/ssdb/docs/php/), but store most data in disk, memory is only used for caching. That means SSDB's capacity is 100 times of Redis' - up to TBs.

Comment: redis on its own would fill up too quickly,  i had not heard of ssdb,  that looks interesting.    i'll look into it